# Using two values in a sheet to filter and return values from a table in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to coding and i've been googling around for the last few hours trying to solve this problem but it seems to be a little beyond what i'm able to do so i would be very grateful for some help

In Sheet1, I have a table which has columns between M - CV (175 columbs). For each column, i have an "ID number" value in row 3. From Row 6 to the end of the table, i have several "search terms" separated by commas in the column CV

In Sheet2, the corresponding "ID Numbers" are in column B. Column AN contains strings.

For each ID Number value in sheet1, i'm looking to find find all the corresponding cells in sheet2 where the ID number in Column B is the same, and  Column AN of sheet2 contains at least one of the "search terms" in column CV

For each ID number, i'm hoping to join the entries in Column AN of sheet2 which match the criteria above and paste them into Row 5 of the respective column in Sheet1

I've gone around in quite a few circles trying to do this and i'm back to square 1 with no code to show for it.

I've tried to research both the autofilter function, and using for loops. The research i've done indicates that for loops are rather slow to run for a large data set.

I'm hoping to find a solution which is as easy to read and understand as possible

I hope i've given enough information for everyone to understand and help

THank you in advance

Comment: Maybe make a example data set for us to work with? Maybe with 4 columns and a few rows? Be sure to show the expected output as well using your sample data. Once the logic/code that is needed is found, you can extrapolate to your larger problem. I don't exactly follow what you need - at least not enough to provide a working solution

Comment: Sometimes it takes effort to visualize descriptions so maybe (next time) pictures of the sheets will help with question. As a suggestion, don't try to do everything at ones. I will use a for loop and a if statement to check if something exist on Sheet1 row 3 and if works fine then i will try incorporate Sheet2

Comment: With all this information... one approach will be: 1) Split the data on column CV on the following columns to have all the words you will search for. 2) If they are just a few, you should consider to use conditional formula `=IF(CV3="Word1","Do this",IF(CV3="Word2", ....)) 3)` Regarding the matching, it depends if there are some matches or just one.

Answer (score 0):

My Excel subscription has expired an I've started using Google Sheets for most of my spreadsheet work, so I tested this there. Some conversion may be required. I did this using formulas, not VBA also, not sure if that changes things for you.

If I understand correctly, you have two sheets with a shared key column, sheet 1 contains search terms across multiple columns, and sheet 2 contains search terms comma delimited in a single column.

1. With this setup we want to bring the search term column of sheet 2 into the correct row of sheet 1 by key using [VLOOKUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup). I made a named range in sheets which contained all my data on sheet 2 and called it "dst". My formula was then `=VLOOKUP(A2, dst, 7, true)` since my key in sheet 1 was in column A, dst was the range I was searching, my column with my delimited search terms was column 7 in relation to dst, and I had ordered sheet 2 by key. I pasted this formula relatively down all rows as needed.
2. We want to construct a regex string using our search terms across multiple columns in sheet 1, into a single cell. I used `=JOIN("|", B2:E2)` on sheet 1 since my search terms were in columns B:E, and this resulted in a regex that looked like this for me: `alligator|dog|rabbit|lizard` where alligator, dog, rabbit, and lizard, were all search terms in that row. Paste down relative as needed.
3. We want to run our regex against our search target cell containing the comma delimited search terms. I ran `=REGEXMATCH(F2, G2)` where F2 was my delimited search terms from sheet 2, and G2 was my constructed regex for the row. Paste down relative as needed.

A screenshot of my completed sheet 1:
[image]

Once you know which cells have matches you can do whatever you want.